# How to check if array elements exist in a string

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have a list of words in an array. What is the fastest way to check if any of these words exist in an string?

Currently, I am checking the existence of array elements one by one through a `foreach` loop by `stripos`. I am curious if there is a faster method, like what we do for `str_replace` using an array.

Comment: do you only want to know if there is a match or do you want to know what the match is (or how often it occurs)?

Comment: @MonkeyMonkey I just want to check if they exist; no matter where and how many times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding to [your additional comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693532/how-to-check-if-array-elements-exist-in-a-string#comment13881089_10693532) you could explode your string into single words using explode() or [preg_split()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) and then check this array against the needles-array using [array_intersect()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php). So all the work is done only once.

```
<?php
$haystack = "Hello Houston, we have a problem";
$haystacks = preg_split("/\b/", $haystack);
$needles = array("Chicago", "New York", "Houston");
$intersect = array_intersect($haystacks, $needles);
$count = count($intersect);

var_dump($count, $intersect);
```

I could imagine that array_intersect() is pretty fast. But it depends what you really want (matching words, matching fragments, ..)

Answer (score 1):

my personal function:

```
function wordsFound($haystack,$needles) {
    return preg_match('/\b('.implode('|',$needles).')\b/i',$haystack);      
}

//> Usage:
if (wordsFound('string string string',array('words')))
```

Notice if you work with UTF-8 exotic strings you need to change \b with teh corrispondent of utf-8 preg word boundary

Notice2: be sure to enter only a-z0-9 chars in $needles (thanks to MonkeyMonkey) otherwise you need to `preg_quote` it before

Notice3: this function is case insensitve thanks to `i` modifier

Comment: since my concern is about performance; is `preg_match` faster than `foreach` loop?

Comment: @Ali: yes for this case. it may depends on the $needles size tho

Comment: you should use preg_quote() before that, otherwise there's the possibility of a regex-injection

Comment: @MonkeyMonkey: added a notice

Answer (score 0):

In general regular expressions are slower compared to basic string functions like `str_ipos()`. But I think it really depends on the situation. If you really need the maximum performance, I suggest making some tests with real-world data.

Comment: `stripos` is very fast. It is not matter of `stripos`; the problem is that we need to perform `stripos` MANY times through the `foreach` loop.

Comment: @Ali: Thanks, I know. As I said you should really compare both approaches using real-world data.